# Why is my PHPmailer throwing Fatal error?

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer

**PHPmailer is giving me the below error**. Please help

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:3599 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(3565): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::isValidHost('localhost') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(2304): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->serverHostname() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1421): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->createHeader() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1316): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->preSend() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\register.php(105): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 3599

Comment: Indeed, this constant does not appear in current PHPMailer, so you need to update.

Answer (score 0):

Considering constant name I'd suspect lack of `use` or lack of global name space prefix (`\`) that caused PHP to look for it in wrong place.

Also as this flag is deprecated as of PHP 7.3.0 I'd try to grab newer version of PHPMailer (or fix the const reference)

Comment: So please how do I do it, please help me